# exclude local addresses in wpad

Tags: dhcp, squid, http-proxy

I have a proxy Ubuntu 18.04, with squid 3128 and apache2, and I publish the auto configuration file proxy.pac with the option dhcp 252.

The file has the following contents:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {return "PROXY 192.168.0.10:3128";}
```

There are applications on some computers within my local network that have these urls for access:

```
http://localhost:8080
http://192.168.0.12:8090/app/bar
```

The problem is squid has restrictions on this type of request

How can I configure the proxy.pac to exclude requests to local addresses? (example: 192.168.0.0/24 or localhost:port)

Important to note that a temporary solution is to manually put the ip:port of the proxy in the browsers (in Windows: Control Panel/Internet Options), and select the box "do not use proxy server for local addresses", but then the proxy.pac would not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function to this:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url,host) {
    var hostIP;
    if (isIpV4Addr.test (host)) {
        hostIP = host;
    }
    else {
        hostIP = dnsResolve(host);
    }
    if (isInNet(hostIP, "192.168.0.0", "255.255.255.0")) {
        return "DIRECT";
    }
    if (host == "localhost") {
        return "DIRECT";
    }
    return "PROXY 192.168.0.10:3128";
}
```

This first checks whether the host part is an IPv4 number. If so, that is directly used as the IP.

If not, the host part is resolved to an IP address and the result is used.

It then matches the IP address against the specified subnet; if that matches, the browser is instructed to directly access the host.

If the hostname is "localhost", the browser is also instructed to directly access the host (although I wonder whether browsers will ever use this function for "localhost").

Finally, the default is to use the proxy.

Comment: A masterpiece Thank you very much. Only a small detail. It works well in chrome, but not in firefox. Any suggestions?

Comment: This should work in any browser, including Internet Explorer, Edge, and also firefox. Check your webserver logs to see if firefox is actually loading the wpad file.

Comment: Your pac file answers my question (that's why I select it as correct), however it compromises navigation. I will ask the question again.

Comment: New question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471423/problem-with-wpad-file-in-mozilla-firefox

Comment: to add servername https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531099/how-do-i-include-my-server-name-and-ip-in-my-pac-file